Bounds for the polynomial integral over a 3D domain
Suppose $V$ is a subdomain of the unit sphere, and the centeroid of $V$ is align with the coordinate origin, i.e.,
$$\int x dV = \int y dV \int z dV = 0$$
Define the integral $M_{ijk} = \int x^i y^j z^k dV$, we want to explore the upper and lower bounds for $M_{ijk}$.
Bounds for Even Terms (all $i,j,k$ are even):
In this case, the integrant $x^i y^j z^k$ is always non-negative. The upper bound of $M_{ijk}$ takes when the domain V has the largest volume, which is the case for the unit sphere. This question becomes easier since there exist a closed-form expression for $M_{ijk}$ over the unit sphere [1].
Bounds for odd terms: For odd terms, the integrand $x^i y^j z^k$ can change sign depending on the values of $x,y,z$. My first thought is using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to give a bound. Say $M_{110}  = \int x y dV \leq \sqrt{\int x^2 dV \int y^2 dV} = \sqrt{M_{200} M_{020}}$. This inequality may not be tight because it's equal only if $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent which is not true.
Tighter bounds for odd terms: I believe there may be tighter bounds for odd terms. Because for symmetry considerations, the contributions from positive and negative parts of the integrand tend to cancel each other out. Is there a way to find the bounds?

Reference:
[1] Folland, Gerald B. "How to integrate a polynomial over a sphere." The American Mathematical Monthly 108, no. 5 (2001): 446-448.
